# jquery function causing doubleclick and inconsistencies

Tags: jquery

I have this function.....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var state = false;
    $(".navbtn").click(function () {
        if(!state){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            state = true;
           $('.nav-toggle').addClass('active');
           $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            state = false;
             $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
//ALLOWS CLICK ON THE BODY TO CLOSE THE MENU//
$( '#colorscreen' ).click(function(){
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');   
});
```

the part that allows the click on body works as does everything but when the div #colorscreen is clicked it performs the functions but when i try to open the menu using navbtn again it requires a doubleclick.. I am missing something but don't know what can someone help?

... a previous bit of advice now leaves me with this...

```
$(function () { // DOM ready shorthand

  var state = false;   
    $(".navbtn").click(function () {
        if(!state){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            state = true;
           $('.nav-toggle').addClass('active');
           $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            state = false;
             $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
//ALLOWS CLICK ON THE BODY TO CLOSE THE MENU//
$( '#colorscreen' ).click(function(){
    $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
    state = false; 
    $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
```

});

Comment: ... so your `body` has the `#colorscreen` ? That's at least what I can figure out from your code. Thought about creating a simplified demo with the issue? -- Have you thought about resetting your `state` variable on body click? Also, why is your `$( '#colorscreen' ).click(function(){` outside of `document ready`? You're not interested on getting your `#colorscreen` selector on DOM ready?

Comment: thank you for your insight , how do i reset the state variable and making colorscreen on dom ready ?

Comment: your edit has nothing to do with any advice... if you look closer.

Comment: Again your edit has nothing to do with the suggestion. You still keep setting your pieces of code outside of the `DOM ready` function. May I know why?

Comment: i am looking at some documentation on making sure code is inside dom ready , short answer is , I am learning :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $navToggle = $('.nav-toggle');
    $(".navbtn").click(function () {
        if($navToggle.hasClass('active')){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            $navToggle.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            $navToggle.addClass('active');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    //ALLOWS CLICK ON THE BODY TO CLOSE THE MENU//
    $( '#colorscreen' ).click(function(){
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');   
    });
});
```

Comment: this worked great thanks ! what was the difference ?

Comment: @havingagoatit Your state flag.

Comment: so how do you manage to remove the flag state and still get the same results ?

Comment: @havingagoatit You were simply setting that flag to add or remove class so why not check if that element has class or not and then perform your operations.

Comment: ahha ! so hasclass saved the day

Comment: @havingagoatit Yeah ! In this case.

Comment: i have voted up all your comments and your answer as it was really helpful... i don't know why my question got voted down but if you wouldn't mind setting it to 0 that would be awesome !

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you to resolve your mystery:

Follow the `state` variable values:

```
$(function () { // DOM ready shorthand

  var state = false;     // initially set to false, all right for now

  $(".navbtn").click(function () {
    if(!state){          // if state is faulty...
       state = true;
       // do this
    } else{              // else...
       state = false;
       // do that
    }
  });

  $( '#colorscreen' ).click(function(){ // (P.S. I'm also inside DOM ready! Yey!)
    // do something
    // Hey, what about our state variable??? 
    // If clicking #colorscreen you want it all like "back to default"
    // than probably you want to set `state` variable also back to `false`
  });

});
```

If you followed correctly the above...
your code should now look like:

```
$(function () { // DOM ready shorthand

  var state = false;     // initially set to false, all right for now

  $(".navbtn").click(function () {
    if(!state){          // if state is faulty...
       state = true;
       // do this
    } else{              // else...
       state = false;
       // do that
    }
  });

  $( '#colorscreen' ).click(function(){ // (P.S. I'm also inside DOM ready! Yey!)
    // do something
    state = false; // back to false!!!!
  });

}); // End of DOM ready.
```

Comment: thanks Rocko this is really helpful I will integrate it right away and report back

Comment: at a glance dropping the use of document.ready is what you are referring to

Comment: @havingagoatit no, as you can clearly see I've just used a nicer *shorthand*. The DOM ready is still there, see? And now `$( '#colorscreen' ).click(function(){` is inside that DOM ready, see?

Comment: ah yes , and actually reading it fully now your comment in the code to set state to false should get rid of the doubleclick problem , .. i.e everything goes back to normal ... i think :)

Comment: @havingagoatit exactly. If I got it right, once you click on `body` (or however you're naming it), you need **all back to *default*** > same goes for your `state = false;` variable!

Comment: hmmm set the state back to false but no joy , still needs a doubleclick on the next click of navbtn   $( '#colorscreen' ).click(function(){
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
        state = false; 
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active'); 
            
});

Comment: @havingagoatit if you just created a simple demo adding the relevant HTML, JS and CSS...

Comment: yeah im going to do that now sorry for the inefficiency , bare with me while i get the relevant code in ...

Comment: ok tried using jfiddle but it wouldn't let me upload external js files in question to make the menu work .... i took your advice and tried Begginners code and it worked ! so what's the difference (glancing)

Comment: even though it wasn't your answer I am voting you up as your help was more than valid !